# Unity android build is failing due to SDK is read-only

Tags: unity-game-engine

> Configure project :launcher
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.31f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
71 actionable tasks: 41 executed, 30 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but, for me, this issue went away when I fixed another error caused by duplicate library classes. I went to Assets/Plugins/Android, clicked on the culprit (in my case it was the "com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.5.0" plugin and then unchecked Android as a selected platform for the plugin. After this, I was able to build.

[image: Screenshot]